# Dynamic data model "Visible Tables" count always Zero

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have added a new system(DB) to the existing dynamic data application. I have registered routes in global.asax . I have given scaffoldalltables to true.

But in table navigation while giving DataSource to gridview, Visibletables count is always zero. eventhough tables count is 4.

## region Test Configuration

```
        TestModel.RegisterContext(typeof(TestModel.CompassionEntities), new ContextConfiguration { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
        TestModel.FieldTemplateFactory = new AdvancedFieldTemplateFactory();
        routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("Test.{table}/ListDetails.aspx")
        {
            Action = PageAction.List,
            RouteHandler = new AdvancedDynamicDataRouteHandler(),
            ViewName = "ListDetails",
            Model = TestModel
        });
        routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("Test.{table}/ListDetails.aspx")
        {
            Action = PageAction.Details,
            RouteHandler = new AdvancedDynamicDataRouteHandler(),
            ViewName = "ListDetails",
            Model = TestModel
        });
```

## endregion

tablenavigation.cs

TestGridView.DataSource = Global.TestModel.VisibleTables;
TestGridView.DataBind();

Please assist

Comment: can you paste in the whole of your Global.asax.cs please

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was caused by absence of ~/DynamicData/Content folder with GridViewPager.ascx in it. 
You can examine this if look at exception for Global.DefaultModel.VisibleTables in debug.